# Java, StackOverflowError when extending a class, or instantiating

Tags: java, swing, stack-overflow

Okay, at first, **I know why** I am getting this error, but just don't how to solve it.

I have a couple classes, a main class, a layout class and a buttonClick class.

The problem is in the buttonClick class: I have some variables in my layout class that I have to use in my buttonClick class.

This is my Layout class:

```
public class Layout extends JPanel {
    public JButton BTN_werpen;

    public Layout{
        BTN_werpen = new JButton("Werpen");
        BTN_werpen.setBounds(465, 10, 80, 30);
        BTN_werpen.addActionListener(new WerpButton());
        P_velden.add(BTN_werpen);
    }
```

Of course, this is not the full class, but it's everything you need to know.

The I have my 'WerpButton' actionListner class:

```
public class WerpButton extends Layout implements ActionListener {
    BTN_werpen.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Again, this is not everything, but it already fails when I just use the code here. And I know why it fails: that's because when the Layout class gets extended the constructor gets called and it will create a new object, which triggers the WerpButton class what then calls the Layout class, and so on. It basically becomes a loop.

Now, my question is:

How do I solve this problem?

I've tried a lot already,
like not extending it but just use `Layout layout = new Layout();`
And then using `layout.BTN_werpen` in my code, but that does not work too.

Comment: You have a circular dependency. Each sub-type implicitly issues a call to parent class's constructor.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I solve it so I can use `BTN_werpen` in my other class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class WerpButton extends Layout
```

So, you create new `WerpButton()` essentially called `new Layout()`

```
public Layout() {
    ...
    BTN_werpen.addActionListener(new WerpButton());
    ...
}
```

Which again called `new WerpButton`... and the loop repeats

---

Why does an ActionListener have the name anything-"Button"? (unless implemented on the button class itself, of course).

In other words, why does did you implement ActionListener on a `Layout`?

Did you mean to extend `JButton` instead of `Layout`?

```
public class WerpButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
    public WerpButton() {
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Besides, this would not have worked if you had a separate class file

```
public class WerpButton extends Layout implements ActionListener {
    BTN_werpen.setEnabled(false); // 'BTN_werpen' can't be resolved. 
}
```

---

You can try doing it the other way - the layout implements the listener. That way you do not need a separate class strictly to handle button events.

```
public class Layout extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public JButton BTN_werpen;

    public Layout() {
        BTN_werpen = new JButton("Werpen");
        BTN_werpen.setBounds(465, 10, 80, 30);
        BTN_werpen.addActionListener(this);
        P_velden.add(BTN_werpen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == BTN_werpen) {
            // handle click
            BTN_werpen.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know.
I've done that already, but my probleme with that is that I get a class with like 500 lines, what I don't like.The Layout class is already 281 lines, and the buttons are like 80-120 each. So I thought It would be need to have the buttons in seperate classes.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion and code-organization. Sure, you can have the **Button** as a separate class. ActionListeners don't really make sense to be separate as they frequently need access to the other variables of the class of which it is attached from

Comment: @LuukWuijster Your problem is that you extended `Layout`, when you probably meant to extend `JButton`

Comment: No because the Layout class has like 10 variables I need to access in the button action.

Comment: If I just put all my actionListners and layout in one class , and have one class of like 500 lines, is that considered "best practice" and if not, what is the best practice?

Comment: You only need one actionlistener. You can have if-else statements for each button within that layout. As I said, "best-practice" IMO, is to have the listener in the same class that has the variables that you want to modify. Otherwise, you need to pass everything to that other class via setters or a constructor

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I will confirm your answer.

Comment: `Why does an ActionListener have the name anything-"Button"`. This line sums up how I've felt for years. Stop implementing ActionListener on all your components!

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I agree. Comes from my Android learning - Name things xActivity, yFragment, zService *always, no exception* :)